# Ssue with displaying data from the website by means of parsing

Tags: javascript, parsing, web-scraping, telegram, telegram-bot

I need help, I'm not very good at JS, and I decided to practice by writing my first bot for Telegram. The bot works without errors until I start making changes. My task was to display information from the website in the Telegram chat, but I encountered a number of problems. When I wanted to display the nickname instead of the ID, I wrote the corresponding code, but it turned out that another value, the website rating, started to be displayed as well. I was surprised and tried to understand why. In the end, when I tried to do everything the way I wanted, I encountered an error (not exactly an error, the bot just didn't search for information on the website). I decided to leave ${nickname} because I need to display the peak rating value. However, I encountered a big problem - how can I display the nickname and replace it instead of the ID with the nickname. And the second problem is that I can't display the current rating value (I tried, but my bot doesn't search for information).

Code:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const axios = require('axios');
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const token = 'TOKEN';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.onText(/\/stats (.+)/, async (msg, match) => {
 const chatId = msg.chat.id;
 const playerId = match[1];
 try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://corehalla.com/stats/player/${playerId}`);
  const html = response.data;
  const dom = new JSDOM(html);
  const document = dom.window.document;
  const stats = [];
  const element = document.querySelector('h1');
  element.classList.add('text-5xl', 'font-bold');
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.font-semibold.text-lg.mt-2, .font-semibold.text-lg.mt-2, .text-4xl.ml-3.text-textVar1');
  for (let elem of elements) {
   const text = elem.textContent;
   stats.push(text);
  }
  const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.text-gray-500.text-sm, .text-gray-500.text-sm, .text-4xl.ml-3.text-textVar1');
  for (let elem of labels) {
   const text = elem.textContent;
   stats.push(text);
  }
  const nickname = document.querySelector('.text-4xl.ml-3.text-textVar1').textContent;
  const reply = `Statistics for player ${playerId}:
Peak ELO: ${nickname}
Level: ${stats[0]}
Experience: ${stats[1]}
Playtime: ${stats[2]}
Wins: ${stats[3]}
Losses: ${stats[4]}
Number of ranked 1v1 matches: ${stats[5]}
Winrate: ${stats[6]}
Playtime: ${stats[7]}
Glory for rating: ${stats[8]}
Glory for wins: ${stats[9]}
Clan experience: ${stats[11]}
Clan experience percentage: ${stats[12]}
Clan: ${stats[13]}
...`;
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, reply);
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'An error occurred while retrieving statistics');
 }
});
```

Comment: Does the site have an API so you don't need to use web scraping?

Comment: @Barmar, there is no API on the site, I would not make life difficult for myself. That's why I'm asking for help from more experienced people.

Comment: Then you need to post sample HTML and explain which fields you're trying to extract into each variable. If the selector for `nickname` is returning the rating, you'll need to use a more specific selector. Or use `querySelectorAll()` and index it to get the one that contains the nickname.